# Changing from x-y to x-z dimensions for dragging using the shift key- Input Latency problem

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, graphics, 3d

As a part of my project, I have developed a sphere that a user can move utilizing a mouse. Since dragging in Unity can only be done taking into account two dimensions at a time, I developed a mechanism to to change dragging on the x-y plane to dragging on the x-z plane, vice-versa. However, the program is definitely not user friendly, as it is difficult to control an object in 3D space when dragging on a 2D plane (IE: x-y plane or x-z plane). This matter is only made worse by the fact that there exists a severe input latency problem. Not every shift press to change planes seems to register, and often I must press shift multiple times just to change planes.

I have tried changing the location of the call to OnMouseDrag() to different places in the update() method. 
This did not work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshCollider))]

public class UserController : MonoBehaviour
{


bool shiftOn = false;

void OnMouseDrag()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        if (shiftOn)
        {
            //3D Drag, courtesy of Unity Forums
            float distance_to_screen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position).z;
            transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, distance_to_screen));
        }

        else
        {
            //Plane Drag
            float distance_to_screen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position).z;
            Vector3 pos_move = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, distance_to_screen));
            transform.position = new Vector3(pos_move.x, transform.position.y, pos_move.z);
        }



    }

}

void changeShift()
{
    shiftOn = !shiftOn;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift))
    {
        changeShift();
    }
    OnMouseDrag();



}



}
```

The input latency still exists. Shift calls often do not register, and I have to press it multiple times. I lose control of the sphere pretty easily while trying to switch dimensions.

How do I get rid of this input latency? Is there a better way of handling this? Is there a manner in which you can drag objects in 3D space with a mouse while controlling all three dimensions at once?

All responses are appreciated.

Thank you very much for reading, and I look forward to your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

As you know `Update()` is called every frame.

So when you hold the shift key down, in each frames the value of `shiftOn` changes because of the function `changeShift()`. so if you have 25fps in 25/2 you don't have `shiftOn = true` and as a result, there might be some lag or latency in the object movement.

so I suggest you change the code like this :

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        Debug.Log("Shift Pressed"); //Logs message to the Unity Console.
        shiftOn = true;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        Debug.Log("Shift Released"); //Logs message to the Unity Console.
        shiftOn = false;
    }
}
```

**Update based on comment**

I think in order to make movement of the object slightly smoother you should separate the **OnMouseDown** event from **OnMouserDrag**.by which I mean you should calculate the initial position inside `OnMouseDown` and calculate the distance and current position inside `OnMouseDrag` so the updated code would be like :

```
Vector3 Dist;
float PosX;
float Posy; 
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        Debug.Log("Shift Pressed");
        shiftOn = true;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        Debug.Log("Shift Released");
        shiftOn = false;
    }
}

private void OnMouseDown()
{
    if(!shiftOn)
    {
        Dist = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
        PosX = Input.mousePosition.x - Dist.x;
        PosY = Input.mousePosition.y - Dist.y;
    }
}

private void OnMouseDrag()
{
    if(!shiftOn)
    {
        Vector3 CurrentPos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x - PosX, Input.mousePosition.y -PosY, Dist.z);
        Vector3 WorldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(CurrentPos);
        transform.position = WorldPos;
    }
}
```

Notice the example I wrote is for moving object in 2D, alter it for using in 3D.

Comment: Thank you for this, Mohamad!
Control is still very hard since the sphere often moves too fast, but at least the latency issue is resolved.

Comment: @IDebarshi you can accept the answer if it helped you. (by clicking the tick on the VoteUp/Down on the left side of the answer). also answer updated

Comment: Thank you, Mohamad!
I wanted to show you my code. I think your solution worked, but I am not fully sure if I implemented it correctly.

Comment: @IDebarshi you are calculating the initial pos in `OnMouseDown` which are `Dist`, `PosX`,`PosY`,`PosZ`. then in `OnMouseDrag` you should use these points and calculate the distance for moving. I don't see the usage of these variables in your code. pls, use my complete example to see if it work for you in 2D mode or not. pls, read it precisely and completely. I saw your code, pls delete it from answers cause it's not working

Comment: Mohamad, just updated it. It seems so much smoother. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a reason to check both key down and key up?  Wouldn't `shiftOn = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift);` work just as well and eliminate the `if` blocks?

Answer (score 1):

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshCollider))]
public class UserController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 Dist;
    private float PosX = 0.0f;
    private float PosY = 0.0f;
    private float PosZ = 0.0f;
    private bool shiftOn = false;

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Dist = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
        PosX = Input.mousePosition.x - Dist.x;
        PosY = Input.mousePosition.y - Dist.y;
        PosZ = Input.mousePosition.z - Dist.z;
    }
    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            if (shiftOn) // 3D drag
            {
                transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x - PosX, Input.mousePosition.y - PosY, Input.mousePosition.z - PosZ));
            }
            else
            {
                //Plane Drag
                Vector3 pos_move = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x - PosX, Input.mousePosition.y - PosY, Input.mousePosition.z - PosZ));
                transform.position = new Vector3(pos_move.x, transform.position.y, pos_move.z);
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift)||Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightShift))
        {
            Debug.Log("Shift Pressed"); //Logs message to the Unity Console.
            shiftOn = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.RightShift))
        {
            Debug.Log("Shift Released"); //Logs message to the Unity Console.
            shiftOn = false;
        }
    }
```